# How to reference a sibling property for use in property name declaration? [object literal, Javascript, es6]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-literal

I have an object that has a property named 'type'.  This type is the name of another property in the object.  Can I achieve my desired output without breaking the declaration up into multiple parts by using Object Literal Syntax.  Here is what I have, help is appreciated.

```js
// desired output
// {
//     name: 'Tom Ford',
//     type: 'random-type',
//     'random-type': {
//         title: 'Blah',
//         amount: 2000
//     }
// }


var thisRefTest = {
    name: 'Tom Ford',
    type: getRandomType(),
    [this.type]: {
        title: 'Blah',
        amount: 2000
    }
}

console.log('thisRefTest', thisRefTest)
// output:
// {
//   "name": "Tom Ford",
//   "type": "random-type",
//   "undefined": {
//     "title": "Blah",
//     "amount": 2000
//   }
// }

var funcRefTest = {
    name: 'Tom Ford',
    type: getRandomType(),
    [function () {
            return this.type;
    }()]: {
        title: 'Blah',
        amount: 2000
    }
}

console.log('funcRefTest', funcRefTest)
// output:
// {
//   "name": "Tom Ford",
//   "type": "random-type",
//   "undefined": {
//     "title": "Blah",
//     "amount": 2000
//   }
// }

function getRandomType(){
  return 'random-type';
}
```

Comment: You can't. Create type variable before creating `funcRefTest` and use it.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing for the time being... thanks for backing that up

Comment: First off, you can't use `this` in a literal definition.  It is not set to be the object being created.  It is still whatever value it was before the declaration started.  Second off, there is no way in Javascript to refer to the current object in the middle of being created.  They just don't offer that.  So, properties that are to be created based on the values of other properties have to be added after the initial object has been created or you  have to store needed values in local variables before the object literal definition starts so you have a way to reference them.

Comment: Yeah I explored the logged `this` objects and saw that was the case before posting... thought there might be a way though.. NBD

Answer (score 0):

Only if you will define a variable with a value first

```
var type = getRandomType();
var thisRefTest = {
   name: 'Tom Ford',
   type: type,
   [type]: {
     title: 'Blah',
     amount: 2000
   }
};
```

The thing is that there is no object at the moment of instantiation.
Javascript interpreter can't refer to a property in the object, that is not created, while corresponding closing bracket `}` is not met.